# Adding Newsfeed to page shows up in "list view" (Sharepoint online)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I removed the Newsfeed WebPart from a page long ago and I was trying to add it back. However when I go to add the WebPart I do not see a Newsfeed WebPart I only see a "Microfeed" WebPart.

When I add that Microfeed WebPart it shows up as a list with about 40 columns and does not show in proper newsfeed view

Any thoughts on what I may be doing wrong?

Additional information

- I can see newsfeeds on other sites i create so it is enabled for our
  tenant
- I can click on the newsfeed item in the side menu and access the newsfeed on that particular site with no issues

Answer (score -1):

You can add the site feed web part . It will show the news feed in that.
[image]
After Adding the web part it will show as below 
[image]
Now Save your web part.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer. A one-liner will not be that helpful for other readers.